# Distance between geodesic rays

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, metric-geometry, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

I am trying to prove the following but so far did not succeed.
Given a $\delta$-hyperbolic space $(X,d)$ (with Rips triangle condition: a point on any side is contained in
the $\delta$-neighbourhood of the union of the other two sides) and two (unit speed) geodesic rays $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ originating from the same point $x$. If there is some $t$ such that
$d(\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t)) \leq \delta$ then for any $0 \leq t' \leq t$: $d(\gamma_1(t'), \gamma_2(t')) \leq \delta$.
Any hints or a proof?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is simply false; take for instance $X$ which is the Cayley graph of ${\mathbb Z}$ with the generating set $\{1, -1\}$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan But in that case one would get $\delta = 1$? And I do not see how to construct geodesics which violate the condition in this case.

Comment: Actually, in this case, $\delta=1/2$. Take any pair of geodesic rays emanating from the same vertex of the graph $X$ and at finite distance from each other. Also, take $t=1$, $t'=1/2$.